# Creating fake components when testing subcomponents via __Rewire__

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs

I've just started using React at our company, all great so far but I found myself writing quit a bit of a boilerplate(especially in specs).

Particularly when testing Parent => Child component interactions:

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  render = () => null
}

ParentComponent.__Rewire__('ChildComponent', ChildComponent)
```

Any suggestions how to extract this to a helper?

The API I imagined:

- `rewire(ParentComponent, 'ChildComponent')`
- `ParentComponent.__RewireWithMock__('ChildComponent')`